# In-Context Checkout: No response handler found for post message response error

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

I use [Advanced In-Context Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/javascript_advanced_settings/).

I do AJAX and utilize these functions, just as their docs explain it:

```
paypal.checkout.setup()
paypal.checkout.initXO()
paypal.checkout.startFlow()
paypal.checkout.closeFlow()
```

And I constantly get this annoying error after [Execute the payment step](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/execute-payments/). They didn't bother to explain it anywhere is their API docs. It is just missing.

> new Error("No response handler found for post message response "+t.name+" in "+window.location.href);

What does the error mean? What kind of *response handler for post message response* is expected? How to provide it?

My client side code is as simple as the following:

```
onCheckoutBtnClick(ev) {
    paypal.checkout.initXO();
    $.post('/checkout', {
        user: JSON.stringify(this.props.user),
        data: JSON.stringify(this.props.WCs),
    })
    .done(res => {
        paypal.checkout.startFlow(res.approval_url);
    })
    .fail(err => {
        paypal.checkout.closeFlow();
    });
},
```

And server side is as follows:

```
router.post('/checkout', (req, res, next) => {
    var payment_json = {

        // huge config to create a payment
        // the pivotal value is "return_url"
        redirect_urls: {
            "return_url": "http://example.com:3000/complete_payment",
            "cancel_url": "http://example.com:3000/cancel_payment"
        },
    }
});
```

And `return_url` code

```
router.get('/complete_payment', (req, res, next) => {
    paypal.payment.execute(req.query.paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (err, payment) {

        // After this step the error in thrown on the client
        res.redirect('http://example.com:3000/show_complete_page_to_buyer');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is a Sandbox problem only. See this error all the time in Sandbox and newer seen it in production mode.
I have mailed the Paypal developer complaining on the many difference between sandbox and production.

Answer (score 1):

The sandbox has issues for me also that often correct themselves on a refresh. Using the Chrome developers tools (Ctrl-Shift-I) and reviewing the console log I see this stack trace:

```
types.js:19 Uncaught Error: No handler found for post message ack for message: postrobot_method from http://localhost:50834 in https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/button
at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) [as postrobot_message_ack] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2514:33)
at receiveMessage (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2465:77)
at messageListener (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2486:13)
```

I've also observed the error can be triggered by unhandled javascript exceptions elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I solved wrapping the button init function in $(window).load()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer adding source code to it, or move it as a comment under the question. Thanks!

Comment: The best answer as it immediately resolved my issues when I placed the code in $(document).ready(function () {....});